# Ampersand executing even when "if" statement is false

Tags: powershell

I have a script where I use variables to call a set of actions using &, and to call those actions I use if statements, and even when the statements are false the variable script still runs.

```
The code looks something like this: 
$script = {
$name = read-host "enter your name"
if ($input = "bob") {echo "hello bob"}
if ($input = "frank") {echo "hello frank"}
}
$input = read-host "Do you want to enter your name or your initials?"
if ($input = "name") {$choice = "name" ; & $script}
```

Even though $input is not name, the script will still run.

Comment: Unable to reproduce this. What are the contents of `$script` and how are you verifying it's actually running? Do you see the `"hello world"` output?

Comment: What's the actual code?  You might have something with an array on the left side `if (1,2,3 -ne 1) { 'true' }`

Comment: `=` is only for assignment, you want `-eq`. Additionally: [Don't use `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4#input) for user-defined variables

Comment: Unlike the intended `if ($var -eq "name") ...`,  `if ($var = "name")...` is _always_ `$true`, because `"name"` is not only _assigned_ to `$var`, but also used _as the conditional_: `if ("name") ...` is _always_ `$true`, given that any _nonempty_ string is coerced to `$true` in a _Boolean_ context - whether that Boolean context is _implicit_, as here, or _explicit_, e.g. `[bool] "name"` See the second duplicate for details.